# yum/dnf update fails: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: nobara-amdgpu-config

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf, nobara

Tried running `sudo dnf update`

but it gave an output:

> Error: Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: nobara-amdgpu-config (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

Expected it to run without any error.

Comment: Does this help you? https://www.reddit.com/r/NobaraProject/comments/17s0nj2/issue_while_upgrading_nobara_linux/

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
sudo dnf upgrade --exclude=nobara-amdgpu-config,nobara-welcome.noarch
```